# Trouble identifying guitar model

Tags: guitar

I am a beginner to electric guitars, although I have been playing acoustic guitars for a few years. I have recently bought a Squier Stratocaster Pack (SSS), but nowhere on the internet does it mention the model of the guitar, not even in the manual, warranty card... I think it may be the affinity series but I am not sure. Can someone please identify the guitar.

[This is the link from where I bought it](https://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/STRATPKLBSB--squier-stratocaster-pack-brown-sunburst)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears this guitar is specifically made for and sold as part of the Stratocaster Pack with the amp and other accessories. The least expensive Squier Strat is the Bullet for $179 and the Affinity series costs $229. Those prices are just for the instruments so at $219 for the package I can’t imagine it’s any of the models they sell as a stand-alone guitar. Here’s a link to the Squier page:

https://shop.fender.com/en-US/squier-electric-guitars/

These packs are geared for beginners who can buy everything they need to get started in one shot. If the guitar is structurally sound (straight neck, well put together, etc.), plays well (it might need a bit of adjusting) and sounds good it’s a very good deal for getting started on electric guitar, good luck!